# Standardization and Normalization of 2d data

Tags: python, normalization, standardized

I'm trying to stand/norm some data:

The data consists of two temperature readings, one from a sensor and the other from a mercury thermometer.

Like so:

```
SENSOR  THERM
32.69   31.25
32.00   30.25
31.94   30.50
31.87   30.50
31.44   29.50
...
```

I want to create a regression model and for that I need the data to be stand/normalized

What I'm currently doing is:

1. find the mean of the Sensor Data
2. find the mean of the Therm Data
3. compute the Standard deviation of Sensor Data
4. compute the Standard deviation of Therm Data
5. create a new list, and add the standardized values to that

Here's where things get tricky.

After creating this new list I want to normalize so it has values from 0-1, they way I'm doing it is getting the lowest and highest values from the standardized data (Sensor and Therm together). But that seem a bit odd.

Here's the code so far:

```
data = [[32.69, 31.25],
        [32.00, 30.25],
        [31.94, 30.50],
        [31.87, 30.50],
        [31.44, 29.50]]

# take mean from data
mean_x = sum(x for x,y in data)/len(data)
mean_y = sum(y for x,y in data)/len(data)

# compute standard deviation 
std_d_x = (sum((x-mean_x)**2 for x,y in data)/len(data))**(1/2.0)
std_d_y = (sum((y-mean_y)**2 for x,y in data)/len(data))**(1/2.0)


stand_data = []

# get standardized values
for x, y in data:
    stand_x = (x - mean_x) / std_d_x
    stand_y = (y - mean_y) / std_d_y

    stand_data.append((stand_x, stand_y))

# find min/max value from the whole data
min_v = min(min([x,y]) for x, y in stand_data)
max_v = max(max([x,y]) for x, y in stand_data)


for i, (stand_x, stand_y) in enumerate(stand_data):
    # normalize it
    norm_x = (stand_x - min_v)/(max_v - min_v)
    norm_y = (stand_y - min_v)/(max_v - min_v)

    # display

    raw = "%.2f, %.2f"%(data[i][0], data[i][1])
    stand = "%.2f, %.2f"%(stand_x, stand_y)
    norm =  "%.2f, %.2f"%(norm_x, norm_y)
    print("{raw} -> {stand} -> {norm}".format(**locals()))
```

Here's the result:

```
Input data   -> standardized -> normalized
32.69, 31.25 ->  1.74,  1.51 -> 1.00, 0.93
32.00, 30.25 ->  0.03, -0.27 -> 0.49, 0.40
31.94, 30.50 -> -0.12,  0.18 -> 0.44, 0.53
31.87, 30.50 -> -0.29,  0.18 -> 0.39, 0.53
31.44, 29.50 -> -1.36, -1.60 -> 0.07, 0.00
```

*My question is:* How should I standardize these data? Should I take the mean/deviantion from the whole data (Sensor and Therm together)? Or should I take them separately? And about the normalization, should I do them the way I'm doing, or do it separately (which seems to give weird values)?

Answer (score 0):

The standardization/normalization is usually done separately for each attribute, as you are doing it now.  But for the purpose of regression, consult

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia/111997#111997

As far as I see there are two points,

1. You can choose the normalization/standardization method you want to use on the data. For example, you can use `min-max normalization` or `z-score normalization`.

Formulas, where A is an attribute in your data set-

```
# Min-Max Normalization (Final values are in between 0 and 1)
v_ = (v - min(A)) / (max(A) - min(A))
# Z - Score Normalization (Final values have a mean of 0 and SD of 1)
v_ = (v - mean(A)) / (standard_deviation(A))
```

2. Implement it

The implementation totally depends on the programming language. For example in R you can use a function sweep to normalize it in a single line

Comment: The things is, when I normalize if I do them separately, the min/max value for the Sensor Data will be 0,1 and the min/max value for Therm Data will also be 0,1, which is `wrong?` since they are not mapped to the same interval. Eg: S:32.69 -> 1, T:31.25 -> 1 and S:31.44 -> 0, T:29.50 -> 0

Comment: I do not think it is `wrong`. Since the original values had a different range/spread, they are going to map to different normalized values.